# Given starting number in sequence, find position of second number

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a sequence of numbers $1 - 12$, with starting number $X$ at position $1$, how would you go about finding the position $P$ of number $Y$?

For example, given $X$ = 5 and $Y$ = 4:

The sequence of numbers would be: $[5 \ 6 \ 7 \ 8 \ 9 \ 10 \ 11 \ 12 \ 1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4]$

So $P = 12$

Or if $X =12$ and $Y = 3$

$[12 \ 1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4 \ 5 \ 6 \ 7 \ 8 \ 9 \ 10 \ 11]$

$P = 4$

Hopefully this is clear. This is my first SO post, so feedback on formatting etc is welcome.

Comment: Did you leave "3" out on purpose?

Comment: "Hopefully this is clear."  Not in the slightest.

Comment: The are the numbers in consecutive order? With $1$ following $12$?  If so then that's just $(Y+1) - X$ if $(Y+1)-X > 0$ and $(Y+1) -X+12$ if $(Y+1)-X \le 0$.

Comment: Thanks @fleablood , and apologies for any confusion. I should have mentioned that I have come up with the two separate functions based on the value of Y < > X. I was mostly curious if there is a way to solve for P with one formula.

Comment: $P = [(Y+1) - X]\% 12$ where $\%$ is the remainder function.  i.e.  if $a = qb +r$ were $r$ is the non-negative remainder then $a\% b = r$.

Answer (score 0):

When $X\le Y$:
Let’s find out where 12 is first.
12 will be at (13-X)th place.
That means, Y will be at (13-X+Y)th place.

When $X>Y$:
Then it will just be Y-X+1.

Answer (score 0):

If $Y \ge X$ then $Y$ is in the $Y-X$ position past $1$.  In other words $P = (Y-X) + 1$.

If $Y < X$ then we must go up to $12$ That is $12-X +1=13-X$ and then $Y$ more places $P= 13 - X +Y$

Or, $P = (Y-X) + 1$ if $Y \ge X$ or $P = [(Y-X) + 1] + 12$ if $Y < X$.